# Skipping "Configuring apt" during system installation on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, system-installation, preseed

I'm using packer to automate an installation of Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus).

During the installation, I noticed that the installer spends a lot of time hanging on this screen before eventually seeming to give up and move on:

[image: Configuring apt. 81%. Retrieving file 1 of 18. <Cancel>.]

It just hangs at "Retrieving file 1 of 18" for a few minutes and then moves to the next screen, without "file 2 of 18" or any progress beyond file 1 ever showing. I believe this is because I am doing an offline install with no internet access, and apt is waiting for some sort of timeout before moving on.

This *doesn't* cause the install to fail, but it does cause the installer to spend quite a bit of unnecessary time just sitting there, doing nothing. **Is there a preseed option I can use to just skip this step entirely?** That would certainly speed up my builds quite a bit.

I realize I can just hit cancel manually, but I'm doing an entirely automated install, so that isn't a viable option for production.

I've already tried the following options, and none of them seemed to have any effect on this screen:

```
d-i pkgsel/updatedb boolean false
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
d-i apt-setup/use_mirror boolean false
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following options

```
d-i apt-setup/services-select multiselect
```

Comment: This _does_ provide an answer to the question. The question is really old so I'm no longer in a position to verify whether this is the _correct_ answer, but it most certainly is _a_ answer.